# cmake "make run"

Tags: cmake

I'm a little unsure of terminology in this problem domain, which is an issue when I try to search for things.

I'm using CMake for my build process. I'd like to make a Makefile target such that I can use `make run` to run a given process (specifically, the one I've just built with `make`). I realize I could just make a shell script, or just run the command by typing it out. If I was writing a Makefile myself, I'd do this like so:

```
run:
    ./path/to/binary
```

I don't ever write a `Makefile` myself, though - that's generated by `cmake` - and I'm not sure what to put in my `CMakeLists.txt` to get it to generate the desired `make run` target.

I've found the `cmake` command '`execute_process`', but that doesn't seem to be what I'm after - I don't want to actually run anything during the build process.

**Extra**: In addition, I'd love to be able to do something like the following:

```
CMAKE_COMMAND_ADD_MAKEFILE_TARGET ( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}/binary )
```

That is, add the `path/to/binary` using a cmake variable, if that's possible.

Comment: So what's wrong with the target you wrote above?

Comment: Whoops, didn't make that clear - I'm not writing my Makefile, I'm using CMake. Shall edit question accordingly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are looking for [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target). For instance:

```
add_custom_target(run
    COMMAND binary
    DEPENDS binary
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}
)
```

Comment: Did you test this? I can't get the `${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}/binary` to work, and I'm not sure if it's just me messing it up - I have figured out how to do what I'm after with `add_custom_target`, though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try it. It is fixed now.

Comment: You may need to write `make -s run/fast` to avoid reprocessing files and printing 'Entering directory', etc..